# Send Message To Another User

Tags: message-queue, progress-4gl

I was wondering how to send messages to another user using Progress 4gl.  We are trying to cut down on the PA speaker where I work and I want some way to notify a certain user/users of some predefined messages.  I'm not sure if this is even possible with Progress, or if there is a message queue that can be used.  If anyone has any samples, ideas or has done this before, please let me know.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You might find this helpful:

> Following on from presentations in Boston and Finland, dot.r is
>   pleased to announce the open source Stomp project, available
>   immediately.
>
> Download  from either http://www.dotr.com or
>   https://bitbucket.org/jmls/stomp , the dot.r stomp programs allow you
>   to connect your progress session to any other application or service
>   that is connected to the same message broker.
>
> Open source , free message brokers that support Stomp are :
>
> **Fuse** (http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-mq-enterprise/)
>
> [a Progress company now owned by Red Hat inc]
>   Fuse MQ Enterprise is a standards-based, open source messaging platform
>   that deploys with a very small footprint. The lack of license
>   fees combined with high-performance, reliable messaging that can be
>   used with any development environment provides a solution that
>   supports integration everywhere
>
> **ActiveMQ** (http://activemq.apache.org/)
>
> Apache ActiveMQ (tm) is the most popular and powerful open source messaging
>   and Integration Patterns server. Apache ActiveMQ is fast,
>   supports many Cross Language Clients and Protocols, comes with
>   easy to use Enterprise Integration Patterns and many advanced features
>   while fully supporting JMS 1.1 and J2EE 1.4.
>
> Apache ActiveMQ is released under the Apache 2.0 License
>
> **RabbitMQ**
>
> RabbitMQ is a message broker. The principal idea is pretty simple: it
>   accepts and forwards messages. You can think about it as a post
>   office: when you send mail to the post box you're pretty sure that Mr.
>   Postman will eventually deliver the mail to your recipient. Using this
>   metaphor RabbitMQ is a post box, a post office and a postman.
>
> The major difference between RabbitMQ and the post office is the fact
>   that it doesn't deal with paper, instead it accepts, stores and
>   forwards binary blobs of data - messages.
>
> ---
>
> Please feel free to log any issues on the
>   https://bitbucket.org/jmls/stomp issue system, and fork the project in
>   order to commit back all those new features that you are going to add
>   ...
>
> dot.r Stomp uses the permissive MIT licence
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)
>
> Have fun, enjoy !
>
> Julian

I tried it -- the code is dead-simple to install and run.  And peeking inside the source is a pleasure.

ApacheMQ is pretty much painless to get going.  This is a really, really easy way to get going with messaging.

If you are an old character-based fossil (such as myself) you might want to skip the GUI samples.  You can send a message with:

```
/* stompQOut.p
 *
 */

dotr.Stomp.Helper.SendMessage:ToQueue("myQueue","a test message")
```

And receive messages with:

```
/* stompQIn.p
 *
 */

define variable stompClient as dotr.Stomp.StompClient no-undo.

define variable msgTxt as character no-undo format "x(60)".

stompClient = new dotr.Stomp.StompClient().

stompClient:Subscribe( this-procedure ).
stompClient:SubscribeToQueue( "myQueue" ).

pause 0 before-hide.

wait-for close of this-procedure.

procedure NewStompMessage:
  define input parameter stompMessage as dotr.Stomp.StompMessage no-undo.
  message string( stompMessage:Body ).
end.
```