# Progress V.10 with non-Sonic JMS

Tags: jms, mq, progress-4gl, openedge

Is it possible to send/receive JMS messages from a Progress V10 (specifically: 10.2B06) ABL application or is it working *exclusively* with Sonic?

If the answer is yes, pointers to documentation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just have to find a JMS that supports the STOMP protocol (like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ), then you implement the STOMP protocol in pure ABL.  It isn't a very complicated protocol so there are several ABL solutions out there (I even [wrote one](https://code.google.com/p/abl2stomp/) back in the day), but I think the most popular and well-maintained is probably [this one](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/message/159354) by Julian Lyndon Smith so if I were you I'd go with that one.

Comment: Julian's STOMP imnplementation:

https://bitbucket.org/jmls/stomp/overview

Another SO question on the topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645430/send-message-to-another-user